# Parallel Processing in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am working on a CSV comparator in python3 for handling large files i am breaking the files into chunks of smaller files and maintaining a dictionary containing the primary keys. 
In the next step i am iterating over the rows in the Main file fetching the primary key and and then making a lookup and passing the specific file for Comparison.
My main objective is to do the comparison in parallel

```
def filecomp(*kwargs):
for row in file1:#checking the main file
  for key,value in file dictionary.items():#the dictionary mainting the primary key and filename
     for k in value:
         if k==row[index]
            startcomparison()#the fumction to start the comparison
         else:
            pass
```

so what i am trying to do is to call the function `startcomparison()` in parallel.So that each comparison can be started as a new can be started as a new process.

I went through the `multiprocessing` module of python but it seems like it is always going to take an iterator as the argument.

Comment: If multi-thread is good enough for your requirement, then you can consider threading module.

Comment: i don't think multi threading is going to be efficient